# How do I sort elasticsearch records based on multiple fields using Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a requirement where I need to sort based on two fields where one field is of date type and it will always have a value while sorting and the other field might be null or can contain a date value. I need to sort records in descending order based on first field and the second field should be null. I am looking for a solution in Java Elasticsearch API

> ```
> SearchRequest('test').source(SearchSourceBuilder()
>       .query(QueryBuilders
>                .boolQuery()
>                .must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name.keyword","george"))).sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("createdOn").order(SortOrder.DESC)).sort(SortBuilders.scriptSort(Script("doc['updatedOn'].value == null", ScriptSortType.String)))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked in my test code (Elasticsearch-7.6.1):

```
.sort(SortBuilders.scriptSort(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "expression", "doc['updatedOn'].empty ? 0 : 1", Collections.emptyMap(), Collections.emptyMap()), ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER).order(SortOrder.DESC))
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, thanks for the answer but this solution isn't working. And also as per the docs, the missing property only works if the field doesn't exist but in my case field will exist but the value will be null.

Comment: I have modified my answer and now use 'scriptSort' as in your example.

Comment: Hey that's great. Thanks for re visiting your answer. And I will try that and let you know. But can you just let me know how do you learn these exactly? I haven't found good documentations with examples for Elasticsearch Java APIs.

Comment: SearchRequest('test').source(SearchSourceBuilder()
.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name.keyword","george"))).sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("createdOn").order(SortOrder.DESC))..sort(SortBuilders.scriptSort(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "expression", "doc['updatedOn'].empty ? 0 : 1", Collections.emptyMap(), Collections.emptyMap()), ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER).order(SortOrder.DESC)))

Comment: The above query is the one I will be testing which includes your solution. Just for your reference. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help! I have also found very little documentation about it and therefore tried a little bit...